# How do I create an button that changes the source image AND the color of the text in a StackPanel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, mouseover, stackpanel

In my WPF web app I have an image and a textblock inside of a stack panel, making a button.  I have it set up so that if I mouseOver the image, it changes the source of the image so that another image appears(same image, but grayed-out).  Also, if you mouseOver the textblock the text color changes from black to gray.  How do I get both of these things to happen at once if the mouse rolls over either, or over the StackPanel that houses the items?  My code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="IntegrationRequestLinkStackPanel">
    <Button x:Name="IntegrationRequestLinkButton" Content="Integration Request">
         <Button.Template>
             <ControlTemplate>
                 <Image>
                     <Image.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                             <Setter Propery="Source" Value+"Images/requestNew.png" />
                             <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                             <Style.Triggers>
                                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                     <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images"requestNewBW.png" />
                                 </Trigger>
                             </Style.Trigger>
                          </Style>
                      </Image.Style>
                  </Image>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Button>
      </Button>
      <Textblock Text="Integration Request"............
```

The code for the Textblock is pretty much the same as for the button.  Really I want the whole stack panel to be the button and when mouseOver the image inside changes and the text changes color.

Comment: Before you slam your head against a huge wall, there's no such thing as a "WPF Web app", Web apps are made of HTML and javascript, not XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you describe it, you want a button with an image and label as its content.  You can place both in the template.

```
<Button x:Name="IntegrationRequestLinkButton"
        Content="Integration Request">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
      <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
              <Image x:Name="Icon" 
                     DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                     Stretch="None"
                     Margin="0,0,5,0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                     Source="Images/requestNew.png" />
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Source"
                        Value="Images/requestNewBW.png" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>            
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </Trigger>          
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Typically, one adjusts inherited properties which apply to the entire control (like `Foreground`) using triggers on the `Style` as opposed to the `Template`.  Use template triggers when you need to change a specific element defined by your template.

As a matter of style, it seems odd that you would want to show black text and a color image by default, and gray text and a grayscale image on mouse-over.  I would expect you to want the opposite.

Comment: WPF Web App. And thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!  Can you please raise my question to 1? Thank you again!

Comment: +1 for a nicer version than my "quick and dirty" omne

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm not sure what you mean by "WPF web app". If you mean Silverlight, I have only tested this code in a desktop application, so your results may differ.

If you want the whole thing (image + text) to be a button, I would say that the best thing is to make the template of the button the StackPanel, rather than the other way around. Here is some code:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="buttonImage" 
                           Width="30" Height="30" 
                           Source="Images/requestNew.png"></Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="buttonText" 
                               Text="Integration Request"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="buttonImage" 
                            Property="Source" Value="Images/requestNewBW.png"></Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="buttonText" 
                            Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

So, this is a button with a template containing a `StackPanel` with a image and a text block which change when you mouse over any part of the button

You'll notice that I added a grid with a transparent background. You can remove it, what it does is it makes the whole rectangular area of the button trigger the change of the `IsMouseOver` property (if it wasn't there, it would only trigger when the mouse is over the image or the text itself).

Comment: WPF Web App.  And thank you!  THis is exactly what I was looking for!  I would have given your answer the check mark, but someojne beat you to the answer. Can you please raise my question to 1?   Thank you again!